# finding key/value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When I run this code:

```
capitals = {'France': 'Paris', 'Spain': 'Madrid', 'United Kingdom': 'London',
         'India': 'New Delhi', 'United States': 'Washington DC','Italy':'Rome',
        'Denmark': 'Copenhagen','Germany': 'Berlin','Greece': 'Athens',
        'Bulgaria': 'Sofia','Ireland': 'Dublin','Mexico': 'Mexico City'
        }

country = input('Please write a country >>> ')
country = country.title()

if country.isalpha():
    if country in capitals:
        print(f'The capital of {country} is', capitals.get(country))
    else:
        print('Sorry, I couldn\'t find this country in my list')
else:
    print('There\'s something wrong, please check the country name you\'ve entered')
```

and enter `'united states'` or `'united kingdom'` as input, it returns;

```
Please write a country >>> United Kingdom
There's something wrong, please check the country name you've entered
```

Couldn't find what I was doing wrong... Anyone could give me a hand?

Comment: Because you have spaces. Spaces are not accepted by [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)... Seems like a redundant check anyway... Just try to get the country from the dict and if it's not present print a message

Comment: If you really wanted you could verify with a simple regex: `if re.match('[a-zA-Z ]+', country)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `isaplha()` method takes into account the white spaces in the input strings 'united states' and 'united kingdom' and returns `false`. 
White spaces are not considered to be alphabet.

You can try this:

```
if country.replace(" ","").isalpha(): #Removing white spaces
    if country in capitals:
        print(f'The capital of {country} is', capitals.get(country))
    else:
        print('Sorry, I couldn\'t find this country in my list')
else:
    print('There\'s something wrong, please check the country name you\'ve entered')
```

This will remove the white spaces in input strings while checking the condition.